# Payfort integration with Cordova app

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, payment

I am wrking on Apache Cordova mobile app wit Ionic framework for UI and AngularJs for core development.

I am trying to integrate with Payfort payment gateway. it works greatly on the web but after deploying on the device (Android) I found it dosen't seem to be work and I got a silly message

> Sorry, but you can't make payment using this browser as its version is considered unsecure. Please, use latest version of your browser or download and install latest version of free Firefox / Chrome.

I checked the JS file provided by Payfort and I found that the problem in this function

```
function getBrowserInfo() {
      var ua=navigator.userAgent,tem,M=ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || [];
      if(/trident/i.test(M[1])){
          tem=/\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || [];
          return {name:'IE',version:(tem[1]||'')};
      }
      if(M[1]==='Chrome'){
          tem=ua.match(/\bOPR\/(\d+)/)
          if(tem!=null)   {return {name:'Opera', version:tem[1]};}
      }
      M=M[2]? [M[1], M[2]]: [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
      if((tem=ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i))!=null) {M.splice(1,1,tem[1]);}
      return {
          name: M[0],
          version: M[1]
      };
  }
```

it check on the name and version of the browser and accordingly it disable the service in some devices using the following code :

```
  Navigator.isSupportTLS1_2 = function() {
        var isSupport = true;

        var browser = getBrowserInfo();
        var version = parseInt(browser.version);

        switch (browser.name.toLowerCase()) {
        case "chrome":
            if (version < 30) { isSupport = false; }
            break;
        case "opera":
            if (version < 17) { isSupport = false; }
            break;
        case "ie":
        case "msie":
            if (version < 10) { isSupport = false; }
            break;
        case "safari":
            if (version < 7) { isSupport = false; }
            break;
        case "firefox":
            if (version < 27) { isSupport = false; }
            break;
        }

        return isSupport;
    };
```

The issue is the returned info is incorrect I am working on chrome version 56 on my device and the result of the above function is version 4 !!!!

so it disabled the service on my device
**NOTE** I can't edit this and use a local version as it impossible to work with offline version because their server check on this.

Any help with that will be appreciated

Comment: Just an idea have You tried crosswalk webview?

Comment: I never heard about it before . but I search and I found that this plugin is the ideal solution it worked now thanks to your suggestion. your comment save my day :)

Comment: Happy I could help